# Replayed pcap files not detected by iptables

Tags: iptables, pcap

I am facing some problems with tcpreplay. I am running L-7 filter userspace version on ATCA- PP81 blade, and I have this following iptable rules :

iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

I am sending pcap files from a computer using tcpreplay, but all the replayed pcap files except those which have broadcast address were not detected by the iptables. I checked it with:

iptables -t mangle -L -v

I tried many ways, including using a cache file as discussed in some of the forums, and everything is in vain.  Now I am totally helpless. I would appreciate it if you could reply my question.

Thanking you in anticipation

regards,

Amlas

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. This is a tcpreplay limitation.
http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ

Can I use IPTables/Traffic Control with tcpreplay?

You can not use iptables/tc on the same box as you run tcpreplay. The only way to use IPTables or Traffic Control (tc) with tcpreplay is to run tcpreplay on a different box and send the traffic *through* the system running iptables/tc. This limitation is due to how the Linux kernel injects frames vs. reading frames for iptables/tc which makes traffic sent via tcpreplay to be invisible to iptables/tc.